# Reccursivley write my output to a text file

Tags: java

So I'm trying to get my results to be listed in a text file, however, it only takes the last output and writes that, guessing due to rewriting over it. I can't figure out how to stop it though and I think it may be an issue of reopening the file to write to each time

```
     public static void jpg(File dir) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String dataType = ".jpg";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i<listFile.length; i++) 
        {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) 
            {
                jpg(listFile[i]);
            } else 
            {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(dataType)) 
                {
                    System.out.println(listFile[i].getPath());
                    Path file = Paths.get(userInput,"");
                    BasicFileAttributes basicAttr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                    FileTime creationTime = basicAttr.creationTime();
                    FileTime lastAccessTime = basicAttr.lastAccessTime(); 
                    FileTime lastModifiedTime = basicAttr.lastModifiedTime();
                    System.out.println("    Creation Time: " + creationTime + " Last Access Time: " +lastAccessTime + " Last Modified Time: " +lastModifiedTime);

                    {
                        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream("Results.txt"), "utf-8")))
                        {
                            writer.write(listFile[i].getPath());
                            writer.write("  Creation Time: " + creationTime + " Last Access Time: " +lastAccessTime + " Last Modified Time: " +lastModifiedTime);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you overwrite the file vs. appending to it? Is this your problem?

Comment: Yes i thinks his issue is with overwriting ... :d

Comment: Yea i believe i keep overwriting the previous data that it writes

Comment: You want to use `new FileOutputStream("Results.txt", true)`. The 2nd arg is for append. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by doing following code change -

> new FileOutputStream("Results.txt",true)

```
                try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream("Results.txt",true), "utf-8")))
                {
                    writer.write(listFile[i].getPath());
                    writer.write("  Creation Time: " + creationTime + " Last Access Time: " +lastAccessTime + " Last Modified Time: " +lastModifiedTime);

                }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but the formatting of the file is atrocious, any help ?

Comment: For formatting you need java  Formatter class. for more help go with this documentation [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). If the above answer resolve your issue mark it correct so that it would help others

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in the "Append" mode.

```
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("Results.txt",true), "utf-8")))
{
    writer.write(listFile[i].getPath());
    writer.write("  Creation Time: " + creationTime + " Last Access Time: " +lastAccessTime + " Last Modified Time: " +lastModifiedTime + "\n");

}
```

Notice the **"\n"** in the second `write` command. It will add newline after each such write and make your output a little bit more readable.

You can also try:

```
writer.write("  Creation Time: " + creationTime + " Last Access Time: " +lastAccessTime + " Last Modified Time: " +lastModifiedTime);
writer.newline();
```

**writer.newline();** will add newline.